# Append to an online text log file from my offline C# app

Tags: c#, logging, text, append

I'm looking for customer feedback regarding one or more of my apps (optional, and they would be notified), so I'd like to send some text to be appended to an online log file from my offline C# Winforms app.

If it makes a difference, the server is Linux based, and I don't mind if the public can access it too, so no need to worry about encryption or anything (no personal details or anything like that would be stored in them).

What would be the C# code required to do such a thing? (Pretend the website is: http://www.website.com/logfile.txt). Would I have to read the file wholesale, and write it back wholesale, or is there a more efficient 'append' operation I could use?

EDIT: Looks to be harder than I imagined. If I have to make a simple PHP script to help with this task, so be it, though code for that would be appreciated as well if that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be robust enough for your needs, but this my solution.
The easiest way I can think of doing this is to have your C# application send  the text to a web script. Since you said you didn't care if the data was encrypted I thought why not just pass the text as a get parameter to a PHP script.
This example is very simplistic; you may want to add other checks to meet your needs:

The C# code would look like:

```
 string loggerUrl = "http://www.YourDomainExample.com/Logger.php?text=";
 string textToLog = WebUtility.UrlEncode("This text came from my C# desktop application");
 HttpWebRequest myWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(loggerUrl + textToLog);
 HttpWebResponse myWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myWebRequest.GetResponse();
 myWebResponse.Close();
```

The PHP script residing on your web server would look like:

```
<?php

$text = htmlspecialchars($_GET["text"]);

$log = "log.txt";
$fh = fopen($log, 'a') or die("can't open file"); // Open log in append mode
$textToWrite = "$text\n"; //Write each comment on a line
fwrite($fh, $textToWrite);
fclose($fh);

?>
```

By doing it this way, basically anything that can call the url can append text to your log. So your logger could be part of a desktop application, run on a mobile phone or a web application etc.

To test that your PHP script is working correctly, you can use your Web Browser as a client and just go to [http://www.YourDomainExample.com/Logger.php?text=Test from webbrowser](http://www.YourDomainExample.com/Logger.php?text=Test%20from%20webbrowser) and check for log.txt on your web server

Comment: That looks promising!... I can't resolve 'WebUtility' though, since I need to use .NET 3.5. Maybe we could replace that bit with an alternative?

Comment: Aha! I found `System.Uri.EscapeDataString(textToLog)` instead of `WebUtility.UrlEncode(textToLog)` to work with .NET 3.5. I also removed the `htmlspecialchars()` bit in that line of your PHP file to make just `$text = $_GET["text"];`, since I started getting things like "&amp;" and "&quot;" in the log file. Finally, I replaced all `\n`s in the input with just full stops (periods) so it would all go onto one line. Thanks so much, it works a treat!

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options.

First, you could check out a service like [loggly](http://loggly.com/) which is an online log file. You would have a personal API key to post data to from your application.

If you don't want to do that, you could write your own API that has a simple Post with a string parameter. It would then be responsible for opening the file, adding the text and saving it.  The Winform could just fire and forget, knowing that the API can handle it.

In C#, you could use either RestSharp or the HttpClient to send the data to the API.

I think the problem you're going to run into, is having the Winform app save the file. If it was a local file, you can just append to a file (without reading the whole thin into memory.) But on a remote machine, you'd first have to download the entire file. The next problem would be making sure that the Winform app can save the file. Without something like an API call, you could run into a lot of issues.

Comment: +1. Also as you are hinting appending to a file will likely to be pain, gnenerating new random file name and uploading it (i.e. via FTP) maybe easier. Or server side HTPP endpoint (POST accepting files) can make concurrent updates issues easier if single file is reqruiement.

Comment: Thanks but for something so generic and apparently useful, I'm pretty amazed it's as tricky as this. Loggly is $149 per month which is at least a couple of orders of magnitude outside my budget.

Comment: There are others, and that price depends on the amount of space you need per day and how long you want to keep it. For example, when we were using it for our exception logging it was free because we needed less than 200mb/day and needed it less than a week.

Comment: You're right - Loggly is much cheaper than I thought as I'd go with the smallest 200mb per day option. But I'd rather the data just stay on there indefinitely, rather than being wiped every week, or even every month. (though looking further, it can archive them to Amazon S3 - hmm.. seems a bit longwinded...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to log into a remote destination, I see two solutions. Both are using [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/):

**Solution 1:**

You can set up `log4net` to log into a database. You can see [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) for the configuration.

**Solution 2:**

You can derive your logging class from `AppenderSkeleton` and configure the behaviour to log into anything you want.

```
internal class MyAppender : AppenderSkeleton
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Subclasses of <see cref="T:log4net.Appender.AppenderSkeleton"/> should implement this method
    /// to perform actual logging.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="loggingEvent">The event to append.</param>
    protected override void Append(LoggingEvent loggingEvent)
    {
        /* Here you can do whatever you want with your loggingEvent */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks too, but I only need a flat text file (maybe CSV). MySQL etc. is adding an extra layer of complexity I could probably do without for the moment. If you have time, and it's simple, maybe you could fill out solution 2, as my knowledge in that area is tiny (no pressure though).